# Making all parameters final with an annotation in Java

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I've recently been working with Lombok--and I'm wondering it would be possible to provide a class level or method level annotation that adds final to all parameters. For example:

```
@finalizer
void foo(Bar bar);
```

Becomes

```
void foo(final Bar bar);
```

Comment: That's not possible; or at least this won't do what you think it does. `final` is a keyword enforced by the _language_, not the JVM. The best you can do is an annotation processor which would study the generated byte code

Comment: Generating Java code isn't out of the question with annotations? Right?

Comment: Sure it isn't, this is even what Lombok does. But again `final` is a keyword of the language and has _no_ influence over the generated bytecode.

Comment: Where does it (final) end then, if not in bytecode? Surely, it does not stay only in source code editor...

Comment: @DraganBozanovic AFAIK `final` on arguments get simply discarded as there's nothing the JVM would need it for. Ensuring that they don't get reassigned is irrelevant for the JVM. Ensuring that arguments used in a closure are (effectively) `final`, is AFAIK a compile-time feature as well (as the only benefit of it is preventing programmers from shooting themselves in their feet).

Comment: @fge Concerning parameters, I agree, but `final` in any other place gets enforced and used by the JVM.

Comment: @maaartinus source, please...

Comment: @fge Errata: `final` for arguments **and** *local variables* is compile-time only. [Final for field initialization](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/all-fields-are-final/#_implementation_support). For the security of the JVM is crucial, that `String` is `final`, so I'd bet it must be enforced at class loading time (couldn't find a proof). Similarly for `public final` fields - reflection can change them, but it's checked at runtime; therefore a malicious final-reassigning bytecode must be rejected when loaded.

Comment: @fge I'm not 100% sure, so let's wait for the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30278780/581205).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Lombok could do it, there's already the [FieldDefaults](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldDefaults.html) annotation allowing to make all fields `final` by default. Doing this for parameters would be even easier. While `final` on fields is something the JVM deals with (by not allowing assignments and issuing write barriers at the end of the constructor), `final` on parameters is only a compile time feature.

It isn't possible. Lombok doesn't do it currently and the author's [opinion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/project-lombok/nGNbyDn0Qps/MDzO5SRhyYMJ) is that it makes no sense.

AFAIK there are tools enforcing `final` parameters.

<sup>I'd personally be most happy if in Java everything was `final` by default and could be overridden by using something like `var`. But this idea is coming 20 year too late.</sup>

Comment: I agree 100% regarding final should be the default.