# Handling of `final` by the JVM

Tags: java, jvm, final

In a comment to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30272407/581205), I'm claiming that `final` in some cases must be honored by the JVM. The [safe publication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27369584/581205) of `final` variables has been already asked and so was the [handling of static final members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3697988/581205). But what about enforcing classes and methods being final and forbidding overwriting of final fields? IMHO this can and must be done at class loading time.

My argument is that

- For the security of the JVM is crucial that e.g. `String` is `final`, so a hand-crafted class extending it must not be loaded.
- Similarly for `public final` fields. While reflection can change them, it's checked at runtime. Therefore a bytecode reassigning final fields must be rejected when loaded, too.

But I couldn't find a proof. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

---

For classes marked as `final`, see [*The Java Virtual Machine Specification: Java SE 8 Edition*, §4.10 "Verification of `class` Files"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10), which says in part:

> […] the Java Virtual Machine needs to verify for itself that the desired constraints are satisfied by the `class` files it attempts to incorporate. A Java Virtual Machine implementation verifies that each class file satisfies the necessary constraints at linking time ([§5.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4)).
>
> […]
>
> […] there are three additional checks outside the `Code` attribute which must be performed during verification:
>
> - Ensuring that `final` classes are not subclassed.
> - […]

(See there for many more details, including what the JVM is supposed to do when a `class` file violates this constraint.)

---

For fields marked as `final`, see [ibid., §§6.5–6 "`putfield`" and "`putstatic`"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.putfield), which say in part of `putfield`:

> Otherwise, if the field is `final`, it must be declared in the current class, and the instruction must occur in an instance initialization method (`<init>`) of the current class. Otherwise, an `IllegalAccessError` is thrown.

and likewise of `putstatic`, but with "the `<clinit>` method" instead of "an instance initialization method (`<init>`).

(As you may have guessed, `putfield` and `putstatic` are the bytecode instructions for setting instance and static fields, respectively.)

Comment: This perfectly covers my first bullet, but I can't find any evidence for the second. I guess, that assigning `Integer.MAX_VALUE = -1` would be a disaster for most servers, but can't see how it's prevented.

Comment: @maaartinus: My bad; I hadn't noticed that you were asking about two separate sorts of `final`. That's arguably two separate questions (your current question is a bit like asking if the JVM enforces `private` and `@Override`), but, OK, I've updated my answer to cover both.

Comment: My bad, it really should be two questions (but OTOH having a place covering everything about final in JVM is better for search). I could not find it as I didn't know about it happening in the linking stage (which is actually completely logical). Thanks a bunch!